# Can I use a jQuery sortable for a mobile site?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Does a jQuery sortable feel okay on today's mobile devices? Does it work at all?

Answer (score 7):

I've had luck using the touch punch library for translating click events to touch events:

http://touchpunch.furf.com/

I'm using this for the draggable plugin on an ipad, and it works great.